# Consulta SQL 2 Bases de datos diferentes

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Buen día, estoy realizando algunas consultas para validación de datos de una aplicación de escritorio. Al realizar la consulta, junto dos tablas de una misma base de datos, quedando la consulta asi:

```
SELECT Substring(A.folio,5,11) AS #DeViaje,CONVERT(varchar, A.fecha, 101) AS Fecha,A.proveedor, Substring(B.material,28,29) AS Clase
FROM TBL_Recolectores_historial A JOIN TBL_Recolector_detalle B ON A.folio=B.folio
WHERE fecha >=CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 101) AND fecha<=DateAdd(DD,1,convert(date,getdate(),101))
ORDER BY CONVERT(DateTime, fecha,101)  DESC
```

Sin embargo, necesitaré agregar a esa consulta que solo muestre los viajes que se encuentran en esas 2 tablas de esa base datos, y que no se encuentren en la otra base de datos (teniendo entendido que sería un LEFT JOIN). He intentado unir esas dos bases de datos con consultas simples, y no logró la comunicación entre ambas. ¿Algo me falta?

Answer (score 0):

he dado con la respuesta, y ha sido más sencillo de lo que me estaba razionalizando.
antes de llegar a la sección de condiciones (WHERE) debemos agregar:

```
 LEFT JOIN NombreBaseDeDatos.dbo.NombreTablaInteres C on A.folio = C.Trip
```

y para que solamente seleccione los datos de la tabla A, en las condiciones (where) agregar:

```
C.Trip IS NULL
```